# Android Studio - Kotlin auto-completion is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, autocomplete, completion

Kotlin auto-completion does not work in Android Studio. 
Java and XML auto-completion are working but Kotlin isn't working.

**Kotlin not working example:**

[image: Kotlin not working example]

**XML working example:**

[image: xml working example]

**Java  working example:**
[image: Java working example]

Comment: Try clean/rebuild project and invalidate caches

Comment: Do you want a code in Kotlin for auto complete textview?

Comment: Hi did you find any solution to this? I am experiencing the same

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes happens to me, my solution is this go to File/Sync project with gradle files

[image]

Comment: I tried this and Power Save Mode ise off but ı was not

Answer (score 1):

I have uninstalled Android Studio with user settings. 
Then I have deleted `C:/Users/<pcname>/.AndroidStudio` and I have reinstall Android Studio.

It solves the problem.